# MacOS/Appkit: unable to see drag animations for an NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, appkit, nstextview

I'm trying to drag an NSTextView from one NSView to another. I'm getting the right events, but the drag animation is not coming up.

Subclassed TextView:

```
class MyTextView:NSTextView, NSPasteboardItemDataProvider
{
    func pasteboard(_ pasteboard: NSPasteboard?, item: NSPasteboardItem,    provideDataForType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType)
    {
        
        NSLog ("Paste")
    }
    
    override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) 
    {
       
      
      let pasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
      pasteboardItem.setDataProvider(self, forTypes: [.string])
      
      
      let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: pasteboardItem)
      draggingItem.setDraggingFrame(self.bounds, contents:.Publisher)
      
      
      beginDraggingSession(with: [draggingItem], event: theEvent, source: self)
    }
    
    override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation 
    {
        return NSDragOperation.copy
    }
}
```

Subclassed NSView to receive the drop event:

```
class DropView:NSView
{
    func EnableDrop ()
    {
        // Registering for drag drop types

        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string, NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.URL, NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.multipleTextSelection, NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.color])
    }

    func shouldAllowDrag(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool 
    {
        
      return true
      
    }

    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {

        // To show a copy tooltip during drop

        return NSDragOperation.copy
    }

    override func prepareForDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool 
    {
        
      return true
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        
        let draggedview = draggingInfo.draggingSource as! NSView
        
        NSLog ("Drop received")
        
        return true
    }
}
```

When I create my view in the ViewController, I do "myviewobj.EnableDrop()" to receive drop events. However as stated above, I'm not able to see the drag animation happening, however, I do get events for it.

Comment: What animation do you expect?

Comment: The Textview being dragged with the pointer.

Comment: Do you add an image to the `NSDraggingItem`?

Comment: No. The above snippets have the entire code I tried out.